# Downloading Xcode from App Store without credit card

Tags: macos, xcode, mac-app-store

I have problems using the App Store. I found Xcode 5 in it. Then clicked *Install App*.

Before downloading, it asked me to log in. I logged in with my account – but then it told
me my account has never been used with the App Store, so it asked me to review my account.

But on the review page, it seems I need to enter my credit card information etc.

Is it possible for me to download Xcode by avoiding such step? Can't I download it directly?

Answer (score 8):

In App store app, if you select create account from menu, you will not be able to find none option. For this select a free app and click install, in the password prompt box press create account. Create a new account and then you can see none option. Any way you have to create new account if you decide not to enter credit card info.
[image]

Comment: There's no "NONE" option even for free apps.

Comment: It was not obvious to me at first, but after clicking "None" you need to scroll down to find the hidden "Continue" button.

Comment: It looks like "None" is not an option *if you already attempted to create an apple id with that email address, ever* (even if you did not succeed, which seems to happen 90% of the time, because the apple id servers are complete garbage).

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no. For any iTunes/App Store purchase (free or paid) you must select some preference for credit card information. However, there should be a special option in your credit card information page to select "None" for credit card. This will enable you to use iTunes and the App Store to obtain free apps and media or apps and media with gift card credits. I hope this helps!